# What is a tried and tested solution for synching files across a Windows webfarm?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server

This is a perennial topic on a very basic necessity: keeping multiple instances of an application synced across a farm of servers. What are the options? Free? Paid? How about syncing IIS settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) or Robocopy for that task.

**Web Deploy** ([IIS](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy))

> Web Deploy (Web Deployment Tool) simplifies the migration, management and deployment of IIS Web servers, Web applications and Web sites. Administrators can use command-line scripting with Web Deploy to synchronize IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 servers or to migrate an IIS 6.0 server to IIS 7.0.

**Robocopy** ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy))

> Robocopy, or "Robust File Copy", is a command-line directory replication command. It has been available as part of the Windows Resource Kit starting with Windows NT 4.0, and was introduced as a standard feature of Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008.

See this article for a comparison between Web Deploy and Robocopy:

- [Web Deploy vs. Robocopy](http://blogs.iis.net/timamm/archive/2010/03/05/web-deploy-vs-robocopy.aspx)

See also these articles for more information about Robocopy and syncing IIS:

- [IIS – How to tackle multiple web servers & keep them in sync](http://consulting.risualblogs.com/blog/2009/12/23/iis-how-to-tackle-multiple-web-servers-keep-them-in-sync/)
- [How do I sync data between two Load balanced Windows 2003 servers?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-sync-data-between-two-load-balanced-windows-2003-servers.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was expecting a wider range of options, but I guess most people are like me and just use robocopy and try not to think too hard about it.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, if it comes to sync web servers most people want to go with stable already tested solutions (for good reasons) and both Robocop and Web Deploy are well tested and run on thousands of servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Web Deploy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/426/overview-of-web-deploy/) from Microsoft? It should do everything you want, including IIS settings as well as application files and ASP.NET configuration settings.